# Wordpress wp-admin doesn't work on Chromium browsers

Tags: php, wordpress

Website built on Wodpress works fine on all browsers but **/wp-admin** for some reason redirects to **[ip.address.here]/wp-admin** only on Chromium based browsers - Chrome, Edge and Opera giving Nginx 404 not found error. That IP address is not even the site's own IP address.

Wp-admin works perfectly on Firefox and Webkit browsers.

I have purged all caches, from WP to DNS, tried to change 3rd party cookie rules and even deleted all cached website data from browser, nothing seems to work.

I have also updated WP and all plugins to all the latest versions.

Also all URLs in settings refers to domain, not IP address.

What could be the problem?

**Update:** On further investigation, when going to [domain]/wp-config, it first results to 301 (from disk cache) and then redirects to the IP address one.

Answer (score 0):

please delete the cache from your cache...
and, also delete the cache from your browser

Comment: I have deleted all cache I can think of, no effect. Also strange that this happens only on Chromium-based browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Might be some plugin or theme conflict. Can you check once by disabling the plugins and switching back to the default theme if that makes some change?